# How to stop special characters in selectors being replaced with flash character code

Tags: php, laravel, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, laravel-dusk

When refering to selectors within dusk tests, special characters are (randomly) switched out for their flash code value.

E.g

`#options1recurring-billing-cycle`

is being replaced by

`#options1recurring\2D billing\2D cycle`

I've so far only encountered the issue with _(underscores) and -(hyphens)